# How can I set up a build target in Qt Creator to compile for 32 bit on 64 bit Ubuntu?

Tags: application-development, compiling, qt-creator, multiarch

I am running 64 bit (x86) Ubuntu and would like to be able to build Qt projects for a target architecture of 32 bit (x86).

Qt Creator allows the configuration of multiple 'build kits' for compilation for different targets. When creating a build kit I am able to select a 32 bit compiler "GCC (x86 32bit)" but this seems to conflict with the installed 64 bit Qt libraries.

How do I install the 32 bit libraries and configure Qt Creator to build 32 bit executables?